# Email a list of sales using Python3

Tags: python, excel, list, email, openpyxl

I am a programming newbie, and half of my problem is that I cannot find the right questions to ask - I have looked at lots of Stack Overflow posts to try to work through my issues, but I've not been able to apply what I've found to my situation. Consequently, I need your help, internet.

I'm trying to make a program that runs once a week using Windows Scheduler. When it runs, it should:

- consult an excel file,
- extract some information from the last forty rows,
- draw up a form email,
- include the extracted information in the form email,
- send the form email to a specific recipient.

I've got *SMTP* working fine, including the form email generator, and I can get the stats out of the excel sheet using *openpyxl*, but I cannot wrestle the information into a useable format to send.

The code I've got so far (for handling that info) looks like this:

```
# Open stats sheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Stats.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('DATA')

# Get the author, title and price of last forty sales
ultimateRow = sheet.max_row + 1
limitRow = sheet.max_row - 40
recentList = []
for row in range(limitRow, ultimateRow):
    recentSales = []
    for column in 'GHI':
        cell_name = '{}{}'.format(column, row)
        recentSales.append(sheet[cell_name].value)
    recentList.append(recentSales)

print(*recentList)
```

What I get from that is a whole ream of text, like this:

> ['DEIGHTON, Len (born 1929).', 'Twinkle Twinkle Little Spy.', 20] ['BROOKE, Rupert (1887-1915); ABERCROMBIE, Lascelles (1881-1938); DRINKWATER, John (1882-1937); GIBSON, Wilfrid Wilson (1878-1962).', 'New Numbers Volume 1 Number 3.', 76] ['SHUTE, Nevil.', 'A Town Like Alice.', 100] ['SWINBURNE, Algernon Charles (1837-1909).', 'A Song of Italy.', 15]

Ideally what I would want to send in an email would look like this, with a new line for each individual sale item:

> DEIGHTON, Len (born 1929). - Twinkle Twinkle Little Spy.-  20
>
> BROOKE, Rupert (1887-1915); ABERCROMBIE, Lascelles (1881-1938); DRINKWATER, John (1882-1937); GIBSON, Wilfrid Wilson (1878-1962) - New Numbers Volume 1 Number 3. - 76

I've written an email body, which is set up to include the list of info using a format like the following:

```
body = ''' This is an email. Here's the list: {}'''.format(list)
```

Any pointers on the no doubt hideous code above would be gratefully received.

Comment: Look at using " ".join(recentSales) to turn lists into strings. And please look at the most recent openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ls in recentList:
    line = " - ".join([str(x) for x in ls])
    print(line + "\n")
```

https://www.diffchecker.com/EEJcuu1W

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, use join.

You could, in place of 
`recentList.append(recentSales)` 
do something like: 
`recentList.append(' '.join([str(x) for x in recentSales)` 
which will result in a nicely-formatted list of strings in `recentList`.

The line to generate your email body could then be something like:

```
>>> body = 'This is an email. Here is the list\n' + '\n'.join('{}'.format(l) for l in recentList)
>>> print body
This is an email. Here is the list
DEIGHTON, Len (born 1929). Twinkle Twinkle Little Spy. 20
BROOKE, Rupert (1887-1915); ABERCROMBIE, Lascelles (1881-1938); DRINKWATER, John (1882-1937); GIBSON, Wilfrid Wilson (1878-1962). New Numbers Volume 1 Number 3. 76
SHUTE, Nevil. A Town Like Alice. 100
SWINBURNE, Algernon Charles (1837-1909). A Song of Italy. 15
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe something like this will produce what you need.

```
for ls in recentList:
    line = " ".join([str(x) for x in ls])
    print(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Elements in a list will automatically be converted to strings so there is no need for the nested comprehension.

Comment: @CharlieClark
`>>> mylist
['DEIGHTON, Len (born 1929).', 'Twinkle Twinkle Little Spy.', 20]
>>> " ".join(mylist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, int found`

Comment: @CharlieClark [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) says it only takes strings

Comment: @SeahChinYing This approach produces the line format required, but only when printed. I need this information to appear in this format when introduced as part of

Comment: @SeahChinYing as part of body = '''email contents. List here: {}'''.format(recentList) where recentlist is in the proper format.

Comment: Can I request that @CharlieClark advise on this as well?